# beautify by serializing class to generate token in C#

Tags: asp.net, rest

I need to prepare some token make request over rest API. I already did this and works fine but as you guess its kinda look like very dirty way to handle this.

```
          var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("Parameter1", tokenData.par1);
            dict.Add("Parameter2", tokenData.par2);

            using (HttpClient cliesssnt = new HttpClient())
            {
                cliesssnt.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var token =new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
                HttpResponseMessage respossnse = 
                cliesssnt.PostAsync("https://someurl", token ).Result;
                var result= respossnse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
```

class:

```
public class ERaporAuthVM
{
    [JsonProperty("Parameter1")]
    public int par1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Parameter2")]
    public string par2 { get; set; }  
}
```

I wish I could do something like this to preapre this token;

```
var token = JsonSerializer<ERaporAuthVM>(tokenData);
```

but how can I make it work this way?

Comment: You can try to create `dict` dynamically via reflection

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov "Talk is cheap, show me the code!" Linus Torvalds. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public FormUrlEncodedContent JsonSerializer<T>(T input) where T : class
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var prop in input.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(input);
        //to-do: get name from JsonPropertyAttribute if exists
        result.Add(prop.Name, value == null ? null : value.ToString());
    }
    return new FormUrlEncodedContent(result);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var token = JsonSerializer(tokenData);
```